# Rank of a linear transformation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration

I am working through Apostol's Calculus Vol. 2, and I don't understand the following question (2.4, #29, pt d):

> Let $V$ denote the linear space of all real functions continuous on the interval $[-\pi, \pi]$, and let $T: V \to V$ be the linear transformation defined as follows: if $f \in V, g = T(f)$ means that:
>
> $
> g(x) = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(1 + cos(x-t))f(t)dt
> $
>
> Prove that $T(V)$, the range of $T$, is finite-dimensional and find a basis for $T(V)$.

I think what it is asking is: prove that we can pick out $N$ elements of $V$ -- functions $h_i$ continuous over the interval $[-\pi, \pi]$ -- that let us write:

$
[T(f)](x) = \sum_{i=1}^N c_i h_i(x)
$

for all $f \in V$ and $x \in [-\pi, \pi]$ where $T(f)$ is not the zero element.

Is that correct? In particular, I want to be sure that the order is: "I pick my functions $h_i$. Then, for any $f$ you pick, I need to show you that I can find constants $c$ that work for $T(f)$."

Comment: Yes, that is what you are asked to show.

Comment: I disagree very slightly with @ECL - as I read it, you should make sure the $h_i$ are in $T(V).$ Ie, we should have $h_i = T(g_i)$ for some $g_i.$ It's possible for the range to not be all of $V$ (though I confess I haven't checked this).